# How can I claim tax credit for a bond that has been frozen?

Tags: united-states, taxes, bonds, irs, treasury

I own a USD-denominated Venezuelan bond.  It expired in 2020, but the US government froze payment so I did not receive my capital or the final coupon. The bond did not default. How can I claim tax credit from the IRS for the outstanding combined amount value (Capital+Coupon) to be applied to next year's tax obligation?

Comment: What credit exactly are you talking about? You received no income, but incurred no loss. It's a wash.

Comment: I received income for the four years I held this bond, all but the final coupon.  I lost that and face value of the bond, a significant loss.

Comment: The loss is not final, is it?

Answer (score 1):

As @littleadv notes in the comments, you can only claim a loss when it is final. For stocks, many brokerages will buy worthless shares for a literal pittance (tiny amount of money). I don't know if you can sell a frozen, foreign bond nor to whom. Sometimes you can formally give up on a business activity or collecting an amount owed. But until you do that, you don't have an official loss. I found an article dated October 8, 2022 saying that the Venezeula-US relationship has thawed recently, so if I were you I wouldn't give up yet.

You won't get a tax credit. What you will get is a deduction. It would be a capital loss, which can offset any capital gains you might have from other investments. Beyond that you can deduct $3000 from your other income, and carry over any un-deducted loss to future years. As with most deductions, you don't get the full value of the loss off your taxes; you only get at most 37% and that only if you are in the highest tax bracket.

You would only be able to claim the face value of the bond. The coupon is income you haven't received, so it's neither income nor is the loss of it deductible.